# Initialization and declaration of array variable of a structure in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, assignment-operator

I am getting an error while trying to compile this code.......tried different IDEs

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct car{
        int price[5];
    }c1;
int main(){
    c1.price[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
}
```

error:

> 7 14  D:\CODING\c programs\Struct.c   [Error] expected expression before '{' token

Comment: This just isn't legal C. If you saw it in a C book or C web page, don't use that book or web page. If you didn't learn it from a book or web page, then you shouldn't use it. You aren't going to be able to learn C by making things up and seeing if they work, at least not until you have a much stronger understanding of the basics.

Comment: (You can learn C by experimentation once you have enough basic information to thoroughly understand precisely what that error message is telling you. Without that, you can't learn C by syntactical trial and error because you can't learn from the errors.)

Comment: im getting this error while coding a simple code. I just made my doubt precise by making it more simple.......

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if you dont have the answer you can skip rather than devoting !!

Comment: That would mean passing up the chance to teach an important lesson about how to learn C. Knowing what you can learn by experimentation and when you can't is almost essential.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid C.
You can only statically initialize an array at definition time. Something like the following:

```
int price[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
```

Otherwise, you must use subscripts to initialize the array:

```
c1.price[0] = 10;
c1.price[1] = 20;
c1.price[2] = 30;
c1.price[3] = 40;
c1.price[4] = 50;
```

Try to read the book 'The C Programming language by Ritchie & Kernighan' to get a feel for the language first.

Answer (score 0):

After this declaration

```
struct car{
    int price[5];
}c1;
```

the object `c1` with its data member are already created that is defined.

So in this statement

```
c1.price[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
```

you are trying to assign a braced list to the non-existent element of the array with the index equal to `5`.

Even if you will write instead

```
c1.price = {10,20,30,40,50};
```

nevertheless arrays do not have the assignment operator.

You can initialize the data member `price` of the object `c1` when the object is defined. For example

```
struct car{
    int price[5];
}c1 = { .price={10,20,30,40,50} };
```

Otherwise to change values of the data member price you should use a loop as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( c1.price ) / sizeof( *c1.price ); i++ )
{
    c1.price[i] = ( int )( 10 * ( i + 1 ) );
}
```

Comment: thanks.............this explains a lot 